# cake php contain in contain

Tags: php, cakephp, model, database-relations

I'm using CakePHP for my project...
To speed up my code I only want to get some types of models which are related to my actual object:

```
$result = $this->Category->find(
                'first',
                array(
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'Category.folder' => $path[0]
                    ),
                    'contain' => array('Rubric',
                        'conditions' => array('Rubric.category_id' => 'Category.id'),
                        'contain' => array('Subrubric',
                            'conditions' => array('Subrubric.rubric_id' => 'Rubric.id')
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
```

path[0] is the param from the url...

The category and rubrics are found but the subrubrics aren't. There are also entries related to my object, but I want them in my rubric-view not in the category-view.

The model relations:

Category:

```
public $hasMany = array(
        'Rubric' => array(
            'className' => 'Rubric',
            'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => 'title',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );
```

Rubric:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Entrieslocation' => array(
        'className' => 'Entrieslocation',
        'foreignKey' => 'rubric_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    ),
    'Subrubric' => array(
        'className' => 'Subrubric',
        'foreignKey' => 'rubric_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
);
```

Here I don't want the Entrylocations...

Answer (score 4):

See this: [Containing deeper associations](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Behaviors/Containable.html)

You shouldn't use node 'contain' in the deeper relations. Your code should look like this.

```
 $result = $this->Category->find(
            'first',
            array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Category.folder' => $path[0]
                ),
                'contain' => array('Rubric',
                    'conditions' => array('Rubric.category_id' => 'Category.id'),
                    'Subrubric' => array(
                        'conditions' => array('Subrubric.rubric_id' => 'Rubric.id')
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use one more alternative.

```
$this->ModelName->unbindModel(array
(
    'hasMany' => array
    (
        'OtherModel'
    )
));

$this->ModelName->bindModel(array
(
    'belongsTo' => array
    (
        'SomeOtherModel' => array
        (
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array
            (
                'ModelName.id = SomeOtherModel.foreignKey'
            )
        )
    )
));
```

Comment: too much "alternative" :). I always hated bind and unbind model functions.